# an issue for "echo %temp%" in cmd.exe

Tags: cmd, windows-xp, echo

I'm facing a strange issue, when I executed the following command in a CMD.exe, will get different result in diff WKS. All WKS are windows-xp sp3.

```
c:\> echo %temp%
```

one is: `C:\DOCUME~1\HWU\LOCALS~1\Temp`

the other is: `C:\Documents and Settings\HWU\LOCALS~1\Temp`

I know, both results are the same position, but the second one will block our some batch file and I cannot modify batch file.

So how can I modify some settings let result looks like the first one?

Would anyone please advise?

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: I think, because the second one has spaces inside it, you need to surround the path by " ", like "C:\Documents and Settings\HWU\LOCALS~1\Temp"

Comment: The proper advice is: fix your scripts. They're supposed to have double quotes around variables containing paths since ages. Long filenames were introduced in the last century.

Comment: @user2511414 Yes, if I used "", it should be OK, but I cannot modify script.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I cannot modify script, because of the *.bat file is on the server's shared folder, it will be executed directly.

Comment: so maybe yo need to check this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10227144/convert-long-filename-to-short-filename-using-cmd-exe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10227144/convert-long-filename-to-short-filename-using-cmd-exe)

Comment: @user2511414 Doesn't help, since the `%TEMP%` variable is used in scripts he said he can't modify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to manually adjust the `%TEMP%` variable for all user profiles on the host in question.

After you did that, check the value of [`NtfsDisable8dot3NameCreation`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc959352.aspx) in the registry key `[HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem]` on that host. Change it to 0 in case it's set to 1 (requires a reboot). That doesn't fix the exisiting `%TEMP%` variables (those are static after being created during profile creation), but it will prevent future profiles from being created with non-8.3 paths in the `%TEMP%` variable.

Still, I'd strongly recommend to get your scripts fixed. It's the solution to the root-cause of the problem.

Comment: NtfsDisable8dot3NameCreation is 0 in all WKS. But some WKS don't have dos 8.3 shortname checking by dir /x. I don't why. And I cannot add shortname by using "fsutil file setshortname xxx yyy", return "access denied", so I have to boot in a WinPE from USB key, and set shortname. It seems work.