# psexec exited with error code 1 - double quotes

Tags: batch-file, command-line, command-line-arguments, command-prompt, psexec

Why does the psexec-executed command below fail when I add double quotes to the parameter?

- It works fine **without** psexec *with* double quotes
- It works fine **with** psexec *without* double quotes!

[image]

The contents of the .bat file are as follows:

```
set FILEPATH=%~1
set BAT_ARCHIVE_IDENTIFIER=%~2
set DEPLOYMENT_ROOT=%~3
echo %FILEPATH% %BAT_ARCHIVE_IDENTIFIER% %DEPLOYMENT_ROOT%
```

Comment: The third execution was just a demo. The point is that the first two give different results depending on whether the parameter is quoted (see blue arrows).  Still - it IS the same batch!

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I was reading where i shouldn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
psexec -u user -p pass cmd /c "d:\GitRepos\runAll.bat a1 a2 "a3""
```