# GraphicsMagick unable to process Unicode filenames

Tags: node.js, imagemagick, graphicsmagick, gm

I have found that GraphicsMagick is unable to process my files named in Chinese. I did the same test on ImageMagick but IM worked as expected.

I thought this might be a bug so I filed a bug report here: https://sourceforge.net/p/graphicsmagick/bugs/384/

Anyway, this is how to reproduce my situation:

- Platform: Win10
- Version: GraphicsMagick 1.3.20
- Code: `gm -identify 獅藝學會.jpg`

This is the returned text from Command Prompt:

```
>gm -identify 獅藝學會.jpg
gm identify: Unable to open file (????.jpg) [Invalid argument].
gm identify: Request did not return an image.
```

Using IM worked:

```
identify 獅藝學會.jpg
ç?.è-?å-,æoƒ.jpg JPEG 3264x2448 3264x2448+0+0 8-bit sRGB 2.691MB 0.016u 0:00.004
```

Although the text returned is scrambled, but converting the file to a `.png` still maintained the same filename apart from the different extensions of course.

### What happened

I found this problem by using the **gm** node.js library batch processing my images, the source of the call is made from a **UTF-8** webpage, so **I assume the filename is passed as Unicode encoding**.

I found no documentation related to this problem, although the documentation states that there was a `-encoding` option, it cannot be sent as parameter on Windows as it does not recognize it and I cannot find relevant solutions on Google.

Please help, is there any easy way around this problem, while keeping the exact filename?

Comment: Referencing this to the source forge bug: https://sourceforge.net/p/graphicsmagick/bugs/384/

Answer (score 2):

In case someone uses the C api.
(You can only give (`char *`)-type filenames. And `UTF-8` encoding does not work, if using GraphicsMagick on Windows.)

You could do the following:

Open the file for input (or output) yourself (use `fopen()`, `_wfopen()` etc).

Then set the filehandle within the `ImageInfo` structure for reading and `Image` structure for writing respectively (instead of setting the filename).

To have GraphicsMagick generate the right output file format, set `magick` within the `Image` structure.

f.e.:

```
//Reading
imageInfo->file=_wfopen(input_filename,L"rb"); //ImageInfo *imageInfo;
ReadImage(imageInfo,exception);

//Writing
image->file=_wfopen(output_filename,L"wb"); //Image *image;
strcpy(image->magick,"PNG");            
WriteImage(imageInfo,image);
```

GraphicsMagick automatically closes the file after writing/reading.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem using GM in `C++`. UTF-8 filenames are not supported under Windows (not even in the API!).

My workaround is to get the short path name (8.3), you can do that both using [command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10227144/convert-long-filename-to-short-filename-8-3-using-cmd-exe) and [Win32](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364989(v=vs.85).aspx). However this doesn't work 100% - and if you want to save a file you have to create an empty one first to be able to get the short name.